# Hyperplanes divide space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

**Problem**. What is maximal number of connected components on which $n$ hyperplanes divides $\mathbb{R}^m$ if *they all have 1 common point*.

In fact this problem was firstly stated in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and even in this case I failed. I know that there is an exact formula if planes are in general position. It has order $n^m$. For $\mathbb{R}^3$ I know construction of order 2, but is it maximum? Do you know exact formula, folks?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How does a hyperplane divide $\mathbb R^n$ "on" a subspace? What is the dimension of the subspaces?

Comment: @5xum: By "subspace" I think OP means "connected component", i.e., if $(H_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ is a collection of hyperplanes through the origin of $\mathbf{R}^{m}$, what is the largest number of connected components $\mathbf{R}^{m} \setminus \cup_{j} H_{j}$ can have?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Every hyperplane can be associated with a couple of antipodal points on $S^{n-1}$ and every point with a [Voronoi cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Comment: As I understood I have to calculate the number of Voronoi cells on $S^{m-1}$ made by $2n$ points. This looks easier at least. But can we make stereographic projection and deduce this problem to $m-1$ dimensions?

Comment: Okay, I solved it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and got $n(n-1) + 2$, but it is problematic in $\mathbb{R}^m$.